# Would I benefit from applying move semantic or return-value-optimization will be performed for function that returns file content as string?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, return-value-optimization

I have some `load(..)` method that loads the file's content into `std::wstring`. It usually process quite big files (up to few MB) and I use it extensively so I look for optimization possibilities (without breaking the simplicity of "load the file content into string" and without generating additional dependencies to other libraries).

**Should I use move semantic here** (I'm not quite familiar with it)? Or the way I've written it is close to the most time-optimal because of return-value-optimization that compiler will perform?

```
inline static std::wstring load(std::wstring filePath) {
    std::wifstream file(filePath.c_str());
    if(file){
        std::wstring fileString;
        fileString.reserve((size_t)file.tellg());

        file.seekg(0);
        while(!file.eof()){
            fileString += file.get();
        }
        file.close();
        return fileString;
    }
    file.close();
    ERROR_HANDLE(L"File could not be open:\n" + filePath);
    return L"";
}
```

Comment: Depend on usage of `load`, if you use it like this `std::wstring content = load(path);` you already use move semantic, move constructor in this case.

Comment: You need to write move mechanics yourself if you are creating a class. You'll have to force a move if you have something in between calling `load` and assigning to a `wstring` that causes the `wstring` to be passed an lvalue. Otherwise, the move is already happening.

Comment: Move is happening anyway but you're unintentionally disabling rvo. The rules are simple: either return the same named object on all return paths (nrvo), or return a temporary on all return paths (urvo). You can mix the two but then only urvo happens. So your code optimizes the rare case (file doesn't exist) but penalises the common case (file exists).

Comment: And by penalises I mean you get 1 default + 1 move constructor, while you could do fine with just 1 default construction if you didnt disable nrvo.

Comment: Btw. `file.close()` is called in the destructor for `std::wifstream`, so you could save yourself those two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code as implemented will keep allocating new memory for the strings storing the file's content. For the size of strings quoted the actual allocation overhead is likely to be negligible. However, there is a fair chance that the memory is not mapped to any cache and accessing it may correspondingly be relatively expensive: already mapped memory needs to be evicted. Assuming code calling `load()` essentially just processes the content of the string, keeping the same string may have a performance advantage. A corresponding implementation could look like this:

```
inline bool load(std::string const& path, std::wstring& content) {
    std::wifstream in(path.c_str());
    if (in) {
        content.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>(in),
                       std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>());
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There shouldn't be any need to `reserve()` memory as the `content` should quickly settle on a capacity sufficient for the files being processed.

Sticking with the original interface, i.e., returning a string, will easily *move* the string anyway: when returning a temporary object or a named variable a move constructor will be used. Ideally, the move is avoided, too, by laying out the implementation to be viable for *copy-elision*. For example, you could always return the same object. Copy-elision normally happens even for compilers not implementing rvalue references or for classes without move constructors. I'd implement your function like this:

```
inline std::wstring load(const std::string& path) {
    std::wifstream in(path.c_str());
    std::wstring   result;
    if (in) {
        // possibly result.reserve() capacity
        result.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>(in),
                      std::istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>());
    }
    return result;
}
```